# PHP : buffer size issue

Tags: php

I am facing an issue, I am trying to print content using PHP object buffer. if the content is more than 4MB then it is giving the timeout.

code :

```
<?php
ob_start();
echo $html;  // in this $html variable have more tahn 4 MB data
$output =  ob_get_clean();
```

Comment: What is the value of `output_buffering` in `php.ini`?

Comment: is the timeout related to the web server, or you get a php error?

Comment: _the timeout_ please be specific and show the actual and complete error message

Comment: @Barmar its "output_buffering = 4096"

Comment: @Federkun, I only get the BadGateway 502 and its on Nginx server

Comment: increase timeout windows, buffers, and buffer sizes of nginx. check nginx's error logs for a more specific error.

Comment: Try turning off the output buffering limit. It's hardly a coincidence that you have `output_buffering = 4096` and that's where your problem starts.